# How to return None if no request is made using django-filter

Tags: django, database, request

Hello I am a bit puzzled on how to achieve this. I have a filter built with django **filter()** method and by default it returns a list of objects in the database.I don't want to display the list until a filter is made/searched how do I go about that?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem with the scripts you have used so far?

Answer (score 0):

**You can simple check url Get parameter before filter.**

Here is an example using function based views.
Here Article model has title field and value of title is being checked in get parameters. If none just return empty list

```
class ArticleListView(FilterView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'post/article_list.html'
    filterset_class = ArticleFilter


def article_search(request):
    user_list = Article.objects.all()
    if request.GET.get('title'):
        # Add more logics based on your needs
        user_filter = ArticleFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_list)
        return render(request, 'post/article-list-filter.html', {'filter':user_filter})
    return render(request, 'post/article-list-filter.html', {'filter':[]})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional Meta argument 'strict' on FilterSet that defines the behavior if filterset is not valid, as mentioned in the docs  [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#strict)

```
from django_filters import FilterSet, STRICTNESS

class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'release_date']
        strict = STRICTNESS.RETURN_NO_RESULTS
```

FilterView also defines a logic for filtering, where no results should be returned if strict=True property is set on the FilterView or filterset is not valid or bound, it is located [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/master/django_filters/views.py#L80)